# React Rendering different Children Components on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

[chatbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxGDz.png)

[profile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I41R.png)

So these are mockups for my social network project.
My question is that when a user logs in he is presented with this view.
There are two parent components THE LEFT PANE and RIGHT PANE.
THE LEFT PANE remains there for the whole session. BUT inside right pane I have to render

- Chat box(when someone clicks on a friend from the list).
- Pending request Component(When the see pending request button is
  clicked)
- Search Friends(When make friends button is clicked)
- Profile View (When someone clicks on the interactive I button

**Priorities:**

- I do not want to show the change in the address bar when any
  component changes. So cannot use Browser Router.

**Possible Solution but in doubt**

- I could use Conditional rendering by attaching some state variable
     with each button click and when that button is clicked determining
     the state i should render that specific component.
- I could use Memory Router in react router in order to keep the code
  clean and do not show the change in the address bar.

**Help**
CAN ANYONE WITH A GOOD EXPERIENCE IN REACT TELL ME IS THERE ANY OTHER WAY OF DOING THIS? AND IF NOT THEN WHICH IS A BETTER OPTION BETWEEN THESE TWO?

Pls refer to the images to get  full idea about the situation.

thanks.

P.S. I can only post two links the other two components of pending request and make friends would be loaded the same way inside the right pane.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to use the memory router Coz it would help to keep your  code neat and understandable for reusability

Comment: Is there any proper documentation for using the new react-router version 4, especially for the memory router because I am not able to find any good resource or a demo or a tutorial.